# Conditional Column Values In Pandas For Each Row in Group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I asked a similar question on conditional columns in pandas, but got a little stuck at work with a new issue. A sample dataset is below:

```
   Name     Date         Type      Currency
0  John  *2017-07-06  BTC              USD   
1  John  *2017-07-06  Paypal           USD    
2  John  *2017-07-06  Fastspring       USD  
3  John   2017-07-10  EU               EUR  
4  John   2017-07-10  PayPal           USD   
5  John   2017-07-10  PayPal           USD 
6  John  *2017-07-12  BTC              EUR    
7  John  *2017-07-12  Fastspring       USD  
8  Susan  2017-07-06  EU               EUR   - Dates Restart Again on Susan
9  Susan  2017-07-06  PayPal           USD    
10 Susan  2017-07-10  BTC              USD    
11 Susan  2017-07-12  PayPal           USD
```

I am trying to add a conditional column, with each date that contains "BTC" produce a 'Yes' value in the rows with matching dates in a new column called 'Covered', the desired output is below:

```
   Name     Date         Type      Currency   Covered
0  John  *2017-07-06  BTC              USD    Yes*
1  John  *2017-07-06  Paypal           USD    Yes*
2  John  *2017-07-06  Fastspring       USD    Yes*
3  John   2017-07-10  EU               EUR    No
4  John   2017-07-10  PayPal           USD    No
5  John   2017-07-10  PayPal           USD    No
6  John  *2017-07-12  BTC              EUR    Yes*
7  John  *2017-07-12  Fastspring       USD    Yes*
8  Susan  2017-07-06  EU               EUR    No    - Dates Restart Again on Susan
9  Susan  2017-07-06  PayPal           USD    No
10 Susan  2017-07-10  BTC              USD    Yes*
11 Susan  2017-07-12  PayPal           USD    No
```

I started by grouping by date using groupby and isin: - Updated Code - thanks to  @Quang Hoang very close to solving issue, just needs to reset with each new Name.

```
df['Covered'] = np.where(df['Type'].eq('BTC')
                            .groupby(df['Date'])
                            .transform('any'), 
                         'Yes', 'No')
```

But I am still only producing values for the specific row that contains 'BTC', instead of all rows with each group of dates that contains a value of 'BTC', like my desired output.

Any suggestions? I am here for any clarification that may be needed, thank you to all who can assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check if the `Type` is `BTC` and use `groupby().transform`:

```
df['Covered'] = np.where(df['Type'].eq('BTC')
                            .groupby(df['Date'])
                            .transform('any'),    # 'max' also works
                         'Yes', 'No')
```

Output:

```
         Date        Type Currency Covered
0  2017-07-06         BTC      USD     Yes
1  2017-07-06      Paypal      USD     Yes
2  2017-07-06  Fastspring      USD     Yes
3  2017-07-10          EU      EUR      No
4  2017-07-10      PayPal      USD      No
5  2017-07-10      PayPal      USD      No
6  2017-07-12         BTC      EUR     Yes
7  2017-07-12  Fastspring      USD     Yes
8  2017-07-14          EU      EUR      No
9  2017-07-14      PayPal      USD      No
```

Comment: I just ran this, and it seems to work perfectly, and cover exactly what I wanted to achieve, thank you very much Quang Hoang! Just a quick question, I understand the script mostly, all except for the .transform('any') or max, could you explain that out a bit for me if possible? Thanks again!

Comment: In short, `transform` is similar to `apply` except that it returns the same values to every row in the group, as oppose to `apply` returns one value per group.

Comment: Ahh I understand. Thanks again, its appreciated!

Comment: Hello @Quang Hoang, I ran the script again at work on a similar dataset, and analyzed the results further, it looks like its still not producing the 'Yes' and 'No's' in the proper rows in the 'Covered' column even after using groupby, any ideas on what else it could be?  I think it has grouped the dates together, but the output is still not right.  My data set also includes some single line date items, which I provided in a update to the question.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Those single-entry dates would not be a problem. You can replace `.eq('BTC') with `.isin(select_type_codes )` as in your code.

Comment: Quang Hong, I figured out whats happening, and I appreciate your patience.  The error was on my part for not fully explaining/examining my data set, my apologies, your code is correct (as I thought) in what it does.  The issue I'm having is that dates within the 'Date' column repeat throughout the data set, by customer name.  So while 'John' may be covered with 'BTC' on 2017-07-12, 'Susan' who's data is directly below John's is not, as she used 'PayPal' on 2017-07-12.  I'm going to update the question one more time to add more clarity, thank you once again.

Comment: @SlimJim just add Name to groupby, i.e. `groupby([df['Name'], df['Date']])`

Comment: Thank you @Quang Hoang, that works perfectly.  If I wanted to add another Time code in addition to 'BTC', like 'Paypal', would I update the code to `np.where(df['Type'].eq('BTC','PayPal')` to have all rows/groups with either code to 'Yes' in the covered column?

Comment: No, should be `np.where(df['Type'].isin(['BTC', 'PayPal'])...`.

Comment: I was actually editing my comment to say exactly what you suggested with the `isin()` - thanks again for all of your help @Quang Hoang, it is greatly appreciated!